# Avoid escaping text with XStreamMarshaller

Tags: xml, spring, spring-ws, xstream

I use Spring WS and XStreamMarshaller to build an XML API. I need to set text values in XML that contain special characters `<` and `>`. XStream by default escapes such characters, so I get output like this:

```
<description>&lt;mytag&gt;some text&lt;/mytag&gt
</description>
```

However, I need to wrap such text values in a CDATA, like so:

```
<description><![CDATA[<mytag>some text</mytag>]]>
</description>
```

I can't find how to customize XStreamMarshaller to avoid escaping special characters and use CDATA instead. Here's how my Spring WS endpoint looks:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = METHOD)
@ResponsePayload
public DOMSource handleRequest(@RequestPayload DOMSource source) {
    MyRequest request = (MyRequest)xStreamMarshaller.unmarshal(source);
    MyResponse response = service.process(request);
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    xStreamMarshaller.marshal(response, result);
    return new DOMSource(result.getNode());
}
```

How do I customize xstream marshaller to not escape `<` and `>`?